# Java Spring - No BasicDataSource class found

Tags: java, xml, spring, eclipse, maven

Im trying to add bean my Eclipse is not finding class BasicDataSource and if I add it manually error stands:

Class 'org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource' not found

Here is my beans-cp.xml with code that has that error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.3.xsd">
    <bean id="ds" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
        <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"></property>
        <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"></property>
        <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}">
        </property>
        <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"></property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Here are screenshots:

[image]
[image]
I added dependencies to pom.xml file and updated and refreshed project several times but error stands. Here is my pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.timbuchalka</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc-template-demo-1</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Ive also cleaned and installed maven project several times but that didn't solved problem.

If anyone has any idea please let me know.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you see dependency in your local repository? commons-dbcp\commons-dbcp\1.4\commons-dbcp-1.4.jar? You can remove dbcp from the repository and start "clean install" in your project.

Comment: thanks @rodgenk, mvn dependency:purge-local-repository did the job